# Issue with sys package related to I/O operation

Tags: windows, go, io

As I want to access some lower-level API to do I/O operation using CreateFile function
[syscall.CreateFile( name *uint16…)](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20210124154548-22da62e12c0c/windows#CreateFile)
While doing so I face a problem that the name parameter is of *uint16 but it should be an array ([]uint16) so that it can handle the string in the UTF-16 format. As we can see in the example provided by Microsoft -> [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/appending-one-file-to-another-file) where [TEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text) macro convert the string into wchar_t array or we can say []uint16.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I said anything wrong as I’m just a toddler in this field.

**(Solution 1)**
[`func UTF16PtrFromString(s string) (*uint16, error)`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#UTF16PtrFromString)
Built-in encoder which returns a pointer to the UTF-16 encoding

**(Solution 2)**
*As previously I was unaware of Solution 1 so I wrote my own function which does the exact work so you can ignore this solution*

For passing the file name (string) to the sys package we have to first convert the string to an array of UTF-16 and pass the pointer of the first element

```
var srcUTf16 [ ]uint16 = utf16.Encode([ ]rune(src+ "\x00"))
syscall.CreateFile(&srcUTf16[0],..... )
```

1. Edit:-Adding solution
2. Edit:- Adding correct solution and adding Terminating NUL in solution 2.

Comment: `[]uint16` is not an array, it is a slice, which you can't pass to the syscall. The arguments are the same as they would be in C.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Regarding your edit, the x/sys/windows package has a [`UTF16PtrFromString`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#UTF16PtrFromString) function which encodes this correctly. Your version is missing the terminating null.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for correcting me. Just came here to correct my mistake as someone pointed out the same mistake in another forum and then saw your comment  thkx btw

Answer (score 1):

I don't really care for Windows API function signatures Go has made, and I have [written about this](//github.com/golang/go/issues/43838#issuecomment-766372358). So if you want, you can write your own. Make a file like this:

```
//go:generate mkwinsyscall -output zfile.go file.go
//sys createFile(name string, access int, mode int, sec *windows.SecurityAttributes, disp int, flag int, template int) (hand int, err error) = kernel32.CreateFileW
package main
import "golang.org/x/sys/windows"

func main() {
   n, e := createFile(
      "file.txt",
      windows.GENERIC_READ,
      0,
      nil,
      windows.CREATE_NEW,
      windows.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
      0,
   )
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   println(n)
}
```

Then build:

```
go mod init file
go generate
go mod tidy
go build
```

I know the result works, because it returns a valid handle the first time, and invalid handle the second time (also because a file is created of course):

```
PS C:\> .\file.exe
336
PS C:\> .\file.exe
-1
```

If you want, you can edit the signature line I put above, to suit your needs.

Comment: Nice one, As you are right that it is really hard for anyone to understand and write according to the cryptic signature written by the Go team.